# Espresso check that intent extra is correct

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I'm trying to check than an intent receives correctly an argument passed as an extra with the following code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ResultActivityTest
{

    private static final int WEEK_TO_BE_TYPED = 40;
    private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "edu.uoc.android.currentweek";

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> mIntentsRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void SendText_checkText()
    {
        // Type text and then press the button.
        onView(withId(R.id.main_ed_week_number)).perform(typeText(Integer.toString(WEEK_TO_BE_TYPED)), closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.main_btn_check)).perform(click());

        // Check that the text was sent correctly.
        intended(allOf(hasComponent(ResultActivity.class.getName()), toPackage(PACKAGE_NAME), hasExtra(ResultActivity.EXTRA_WEEK, WEEK_TO_BE_TYPED)));
    }

}
```

The problem comes when I try to execute this Test, it throws me the following error:

> Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process
>   crashed.'

I have the following on build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
}
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Ever found out what this was?

Comment: I've finally solved removing the project and creating a new one.